# MySQL returns query, but the connection does not close

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, knex.js

I'm trying to run this js code to access MySQL/MariaDB server (at this point, i've tried both).

```
const knex = require('../connection')
const mysql = require('mysql2');
 

function getDifficulty(){
    /*
    return knex.select('*').from('tb_dificuldades').limit(9)
        .then((results) => {
            console.log("GOT RESULTS!")
            return results
        })
    */
    // create the connection to database
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: ''
    })
    const results = connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM tb_dificuldades;',
        function(err, results, fields) {
          console.log(results); // results contains rows returned by server
          console.log(fields); // fields contains extra meta data about results, if available
          return results
        }
    )
    return results
 
}

getDifficulty()
```

<knexfile.js>

```
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    development: {
        client: 'mysql2',
        version: '5.7',
        connection: {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
            user: process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '',
            database: process.env.DB_NAME || '',
        },
        migrations: {
            tableName: 'knex_migrations',
            directory: `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations')}`
        },
        seeds: {
            directory: `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'seeds')}`
        }
    }
}
```

<connection.js>

```
require('dotenv').config()

const knexfile = require('../../knexfile')
const knex = require('knex')(knexfile[process.env.ENV || 'development'])

module.exports = knex
```

The results and fields get printed, but the connection doesn't close, so the code stops executing on the callback function.

Environment:

```
OS:Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
D:Docker version 19.03.13
DC:docker-compose version 1.21.0
DB:MariaDB & MySQL (docker)
IP:localhost(docker-proxy); db(docker-dns)
CLIENT: mysql & mysql2 (nodejs); knexjs
```

I've tried already changing from mysql to mariadb; 
Originally I was using knex with mysql, then tried mysql2, then mysql2 without knex; 
I'm using DBeaver throught localhost (docker-proxy) and the same query is working just fine; 
Knex migrations ands seed are working too; 

Expected:

```
[...]
 columnType: 3,
    flags: 4097,
    decimals: 0
  }
]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.305 seconds
```

Got:

```
[...]
 columnType: 3,
    flags: 4097,
    decimals: 0
  }
]

[Done] exited with code=null in 18.594 seconds

OBS: exited after aborting process, also this query shouldn't take 18s
and it isn't taking that long.
It does return what I expect, but the client holds the connection.
So, my program freezes after running the query. (Not happening in DBeaver)
```

EDIT1: With knex.destroy() the program works fine, but is it the expected usage?

```
return knex.select('*').from('tb_dificuldades').limit(9)
        .then((results) => {
            console.log("GOT RESULTS!")
            console.log(results)
            knex.destroy()
            return results
        })
```

Comment: Can you explain what is your question and what are you expecting?

Comment: Hello @Hendry, just added some more info

Answer (score 1):

You don't need close connection after each query, just reuse it in other part of application. If you sure that you need to close connection just close it manually.

For example with Knex you can do it in this way

```js
knex.destroy();
```

[example](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/knex/destroy)

[documentation](http://knexjs.org)

Comment: Sure, I dont need to destroy the connection. But the program is freezing, after the mysql returns the result of the query

Comment: try destroy connection in callback of your query and take a look whether it helps

Comment: yeah, detroying the connection helped. the program works just fine. But I've never used knex this way before. Is this the expected behavior with mysql? Mostly I used it with postgres. See EDIT 1

Comment: properly all connections should be closed at the end of application. Usually framework does it under the hood, but sometimes you have to handle it manually. So as an answer - yes, from my prospective it's expected behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've done that when using mysql with python. But for example, in mysql2 documents, they only close connections when using pools. And other codes I did with knex, i don't close the connections explicitly. Idk if it's a issue with the js version?? I was using it with ts before.